# IP.Board, Использование переменной в signature_separator

Tags: php, ipb

ЦКак в Global Templates > signature_separator (в подпись) вывести имя пользователя подписи?

```
{$post['members_display_name']}
```

или

```
{$member['members_display_name']}
```

или

```
{$author['members_display_name']}
```

и т.д ничего не выводят

```
$this->memberData['members_display_name']}
```

выводит имя того человека, который смотрит подпись. Что я делаю не так, как правильно использовать переменные и как вывести имя "хозяина" подписи?

IP.Board 3.4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак не вывести, в этот шаблон передается только подпись автора, его id и можно ли скрыть подпись. Могу конечно костыль предложить, но будет +1 запрос на каждый пост, исправлять исходники тоже наверное не вариант...

Хотя.

**Костыль (лучше не использовать - +1 запрос на пост!)**

Сначала добавить в этот шаблон:

```
<php>
    $author = $author_id ? IPSMember::load($author_id, 'all') : null;
</php>
```

Потом там можно будет использовать:

```
<if test="$author">{$author['members_display_name']}</if>
```

**Правим исходники (для тех кому все равно)**

Находим в файле `admin/applications/forums/sources/classes/topics.php` строка ~`2134`:

```
$post['signature'] = $this->registry->output->getTemplate( 'global' )->signature_separator( $poster['signature'], $poster['author_id'], IPSMember::isIgnorable( $poster['member_group_id'], $poster['mgroup_others'] ) );
```

Заменяем на:

```
$post['signature'] = $this->registry->output->getTemplate( 'global' )->signature_separator( $poster['signature'], $poster['author_id'], IPSMember::isIgnorable( $poster['member_group_id'], $poster['mgroup_others'] ), $poster );
```

Далее идем в админку и меняем параметры этого шаблона на:

```
$sig="", $author_id=0, $can_ignore=true, $author=null
```

И потом там можно будет использовать:

```
<if test="$author">{$author['members_display_name']}</if>
```

Comment: спасибо, первый вариант работает, 2-й не проверял. Чем грозит модификация исходника?

Comment: Проблемами с обновлением (не помню сколько еще поддерживают эту версию).

Comment: ясно, спасибо за информацию.